# Mockito Mocking not working as expected during functional test

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, functional-testing

I have a two classes let's say classA and classB. classA calls a method in classB which saves some value in a database using the DaoClass.

I have to test if the values are getting saved in database.

```
@Mocks
private DaoClass dao;

@Mocks
private ClassB B;

@InjectMocks
private ClassA A;

A.someMethod(someArgument);
verify(B).someOtherMethod(someOtherArgument);
verify(dao).save(theCorrectValue);
```

This fails saying there were zero interactions with this mock. Wanted but not invoked dao.save(). Whereas B.someOtherMethod() was invoked.

I am new to development and testing and my understanding was that I just have to mock call a method in my first class and then that call would proceed like a normal call and all the methods in all the other classes would be called normally. But it seems that it only calls a method in classB and then does not do anything in classB. For example, I debugged by creating breakpoints all over ClassB:

```
ClassB someOtherMethod{
SomeCode;
SomeCode;
dao.save();
someCode;
return Something; }
```

In debugger I can see it goes to ClassB someOtherMethod() but after that it skips all the code and goes to return statement. Am I missing something? Do I need to go through some documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to either

1. stub the ClassB someOtherMethod. Note that if you don't specify the return value of any of the mocked dependencies (with when()) it will return the default value for the return type - null for objects, 0 for primitive numbers, false for boolean, etc. This is why you must be getting Null when someOtherMethod is called.
2. Use Spy instead of Mock. if you want to call external service and perform calling of real dependency, or simply say, you want to run the program as it is and just stub specific methods, then use spy.